# how do I continue on the function without exiting after else statement in c++

Tags: c++

Hello so my question is how do I continue on with new inputs after an else statement? In my program, I wrote an else statement that if the input is neither 1 nor 2, the user has to put a new value to get the result he/she wants. But after my else statement, my program shuts down. I don't know how to fix this. I'm very new to c++ so please keep harsh comments to yourself...
Here's my code:

```
// This program will allow the user to input from the keyboard 
// whether the last word to the following proverb should be party or country:
// "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their _______"
// Inputting a 1 will use the word party. A 2 will use the word country.



#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


void writeProverb(int);


int main ()
 {

int wordCode;

cout << "Given the phrase:" << endl;
cout << "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their ___" << endl;
cout << "Input a 1 if you want the sentence to be finished with party" << endl;
cout << "Input a 2 if you want the sentence to be finished with country." << endl;
cout << "Please input your choice now" << endl;
cin  >> wordCode;
cout << endl;
    writeProverb(wordCode);

return 0;
}



 void writeProverb (int number)


{
if (number == 1)
    cout << "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their      party." << endl;

else if (number == 2)   
    cout << "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country." << endl;

else
{
    cout << "I'm sorry but that is an incorrect choice: Please input a 1 or 2"  << endl;
 } 


 }
```

So basically, after the else statement, I want my program to wait for the user to enter 1 or 2 instead of just shutting down.

Comment: format your code before posting.

Comment: Will be more careful next time. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 5):

```
do {
    cout << "Please input your choice now" << endl;
    cin  >> wordCode;
    cout << endl;
    writeProverb(wordCode);
}while (wordCode != 1 && wordCode != 2);
```

This code exits if user inputs 1 or 2. Stays otherwise.

Comment: Thank you so much Sakthi. I tried this earlier but my mistake was to have left the "writeProverb(wordCode)" outside of the loop. It obviously didn't work so I thought do-while wasn't the way to go about it. I definitely need to get more familiar with loops. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You want to have a `do-while` construct until you get a legal value, as Sakthi Kumar already pointed out.

*However*, you do not want to move the knowledge of what a legal value is up to main. Therefore, have the `writeProverb` method return if the value is legal or not. This keeps things in the proper abstraction level. You should also consider updating the "menu" printing by using an object, thus tying everything together.

```
// ... in main()
    do {
        cout << "Please input your choice now" << endl;
        cin  >> wordCode;
        cout << endl;
        writeProverb(wordCode);
    } while( !writeProverbIfLegalNumber(wordCode) );
}

bool writeProverbIfLegalNumber (int number) {
    if (number == 1) {
        cout << "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their      party." << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else if (number == 2) {
        cout << "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country." << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "I'm sorry but that is an incorrect choice: Please input a 1 or 2"  << endl;
    } 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure an object would be a good idea, since this appears to be basic intro-level stuff. Going too far too fast might just cause confusion. I like the idea of keeping the decision of "is this legal or not?" in `writeProverb`, though, +1 for that.

Comment: Computerfreaker is right, it's a very basic intro-level stuff... Haven't really learned about boolean, but thanks for your help still!

Answer (score 0):

This is basic logic, you should read about loops and how to use them. This `while` loop continues while wordCode is *not* between 1 and 2 inclusive; in other words, it continues until you get 1 or 2.

```
int main ()
{

    int wordCode;

    cout << "Given the phrase:" << endl;
    cout << "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their ___" << endl;
    cout << "Input a 1 if you want the sentence to be finished with party" << endl;
    cout << "Input a 2 if you want the sentence to be finished with country." << endl;



    do
    {
       cout << "Please input your choice now 1 or 2: " << endl;
       cin  >> wordCode;

    } while(!(1 <= wordCode && wordCode <=2));

    cout <<endl;
    writeProverb(wordCode);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure they'd actually want the program to potentially continue infinitely. Technically they can just close the command-line, but usually there's an option to break the loop and exit, much like Sakthi Kumar's answer above.

Comment: I know that but I think that someone is just trying to get his/her homework done for free. You can't teach someone to think by giving him/her the solution.

Comment: Thanks mcl, but I'm not trying to get this homework done for free. I've been trying to work it out myself for 2 hours now and like I said, I'm new to programming generally. Though I read about loops I'm still not familiar with when to apply it or not. Apparently I need more practice. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: Ok see the updated answer. Basically the best thing to do is to make the user input values WHILE he/she gets the correct one. Then use it as you like.

Comment: You may also want to put a getch(); right before the return 0; in the main() function. That will stop the console window from closing itself when the program is finished. #include <conio.h> for getch();

Comment: I haven't learned about getch() yet but it sounds useful. I will read more about it, thanks!

Comment: @weathergirl `getch` is short for getcharacter, iirc. It reads one character from standard input. So if you call `getch` at the end of your program, it will wait for that one character of input, and your program won't end right away.

Answer (score 0):

in this case,you can put the judging statement in the "main" function. You can use a "while" statement to control the logic.

```
boolean flag = true;
while(flag){
    cout<<"input";
    cin>>wordCode;
    if(wordCode==1 || wordCode==2){
        flag=false;
        writeProverb(wordCode);
    }
}
```